# installing qemu/kvm machine - stuck somehwat at install

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

ubuntu 1404 server here, virsh 1.2.2
I am trying to install ubuntu to an existing (but yet empty) qcow2 image witht the following command

```
sudo virt-install --name myVM --ram 512 \
--disk path=/path/to/image.qcow2 \
--location /path/to/ubuntu-16.04.1-server-amd64.iso
```

> Starting install...
>   Retrieving file version.info...
>   |  116 B     00:00 ... Retrieving file linux...
>   |  13 MB     00:00 ... Retrieving file initrd.gz...
>   |  72 MB     00:00 ... Creating domain...
>   |    0 B     00:01 Connected to domain myVM Escape character is ^]

if I check on another console (`virsh list --all`) I see that the machine is running, but now I am honestly stuck with no real cpnmcept hpw to 'get inside'.

tried `virsh connect qemu:///system myVM` which returns an error

> error: unexpected data 'myVM'

I am used to access VM's via ssh but naturally for a freshly started one with no configurations present inside that's a dead end. So there mus be a way through the standard console, any pointers?

Neither can I stop the new created VM (`sudo virsh shutdown myVM`) it just keeps running

Comment: simplifying the question you could also ask ...  **_"how to access a kvm/qemu machine from the hosts command line?"_**